# Looking for a word for something whose inclusion implies the exclusion of another entity

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word similar to "exclusive", maybe is exactly this one, but I am confused by the fact that in my language (Spanish) there are two similar words that are used differently to express this nuance.

There is "exclusivo" (exclusive), which is used to express something that is limited or restricted to a certain group, for example: "an exclusive club",

Then there is "excluyente", which I don't know if has a direct translation. It refers to something whose inclusion implies the exclusion of another entity, for example: "behaving as a particle or a wave are not mutually *excluyentes* in the mark of Quantum mechanics", or "being at the park or at home at the same time are logically *excluyentes*"

Comment: Hi Arnold. In English, "exclusive" may carry the same connotation as in Spanish. ie an exclusive club. The other word you want is probably 2 words: _mutually exclusive_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the phrase "[mutually exclusive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mutually-exclusive?s=t)":

> of or relating to a situation involving two or more events,
>   possibilities, etc., in which the occurrence of one precludes the
>   occurrence of the other: mutually exclusive plans of action.