# Opposite of causality

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a word which describes the relationship between two things when one thing prevents the other? For example, to fill in the sentence "there is ___ between resistance and flow"?

Comment: Isn't it still causality? An increase in resistance causes a reduction in flow, and vice versa.

Comment: The is an *inverse* relationship between resistance and flow.

Comment: @KillingTime not vice versa.

Comment: A causes B ~////~ A disallows B **or** A discourages (metaphorically) B. 'Privation' is related.

Comment: "there is no relationship | discernible cause between resistance and flow"

Comment: It's not a single word, but the phrase is "inverse relationship" or "inverse correlation".

Comment: It's still causality, it's just causing the opposite effect. Pressing on the accelerator causes an increase in speed, pressing on the brake causes a decrease in speed.

Comment: *mutual exclusivity*?

Comment: I do think inverse correlation/causality satisfies the causal part quite nicely. Mutual exclusivity I believe should also suffice for my purposes. I'll keep these in mind; thank you for your answers!

Comment: `Conflict` ?  If one is feeling adventurous,  one can also try `contrariety` though it means something very specific.

Comment: Do you mean as your example sentence rather 'War and peace are _mutually exclusive_'? (duplicate [looking for a word for something whose inclusion implies the exclusion of another thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380695/looking-for-a-word-for-something-whose-inclusion-implies-the-exclusion-of-another)? ...

Comment: Or 'Over 50 mph, there is an inverse correlation between speed and fuel efficiency'? (duplicate [how to say in a compact way 'an increase of something is due to a decrease in something else](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/557938/how-to-say-in-a-compact-way-an-increase-of-something-is-due-to-decrease-in-some/557946#557946)) –

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am always impressed at your assiduity in seeking duplicates from years long gone by. This seems an interesting double one. A sort of hyperquestion?

Comment: @Anton Bloat makes ELU far harder to search (for duplicates as well as in order to find material addressing queries). The whole point of the duplicate CV is to get rid of the same thing being addressed in different places. ELU is intended as a readily searchable repository of endorsable analysis, and constructions and words/phrases to fit certain requirements. Not, primarily, a Q & A site.

Answer (score 2):

As you pose the question in your first sentence, two words would do the job. As you ask the question, if one thing is present, the other thing is not.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exclusive)
> *mutually exclusive*
> not possible at the same time:

Hence there is mutual exclusivity between the two. They are mutually exclusive.

However, if (as in your second sentence relating to flow and resistance) you have a more gradual version in mind where one ***inhibits*** the other rather than prohibiting it, then there is an inverse relation (see good comments) between them, or they are negatively correlated. Increase in one is associated with reduction of the other.

Comment: A duplicate, whichever sense OP intends.

Answer (score 1):

irreconcilable defined as **impossible to find agreement between or with, or impossible to deal with** in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irreconcilable).

So, it can be used to complete the sentence in OP.

> there is an **irreconcilability**  between resistance and flow.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 'irreconcilability'? And I'd expect a noncount usage (even though these words are rare), without the article _a_, in line with the usage of _agreement_ in  'Concord is the need for grammatical agreement between the different parts of speech in a sentence'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for your note, the answer has been edited. It seems I made a mistake, since I was in a bit of a rush when posting the answer :(

Comment: The article is not essential. // OP's example sentence could be improved upon, as well as their definition of the question (see my comments).

Answer (score 0):

***Prevention***

> the act of preventing; effectual hindrance ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prevention))

However, the verb ***prevent*** or ***hinder*** may be more successful in your example. So you could say:

> Resistance and flow are two processes that *prevent/hinder* each other.

Comment: I don't think that flow affects resistance.

Comment: *Fire prevention* and *shoplifting prevention* would refer to *actions and measures*  whose goal is to make fires and shoplifting less likely. The word refers to actions **intended** to keep something from happening.  We would not say that gravity is a prevention because it keeps stones from rolling uphill, or that low temperature per se is a prevention in that it  cause the pressure in a sealed system not to rise; but *intentionally* lowering the temperature could be called a prevention, or a preventive measure.